# Wrong redirect path for open graph object

Tags: facebook-graph-api, object, redirect, url-rewriting

I try to get facebook working with my website. I created all required meta tags in my site and each object is unique via its url:

http://DOMAIN/#!tvoice/244016

Debugging this link via the facebook debugger, facebook will extract metadata from: http://DOMAIN/

But thats not the object link. Its the main website. I think that the main problem is the creation of the object url with #!. But this is used by many websites (esp. twitter). So there should be a way to get this right.

Do you know a way to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a php url scheme for my site, like `/?fbid=4` which is id 4 on facebook, in your case you may need to create the same `domain.com/?id=244016&catagory=tvoice`

Comment: Hey, i just have a javascript routing with ajax hashes. So i need to include php for that? Dont really know how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of things the laft few days but its really impossible to "create" the meta tags via javascript or something else onb the client side because of the facebook crawler.

Like Shawn said, you have to deliver the meta tags from the server side.

Comment: if your creating meta tags with javascript, keep in mind javascript runs client side so the metatags get changed after the webcrawlers crawl, so facebook, google and search engines will see the tags before the change.  You need to change those tags dynamicly with php or server side.